# Trying to begin a storyboard on change of a property in WPF application

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, properties, storyboard

I have a simple MVVM application. It contains a property, which I will change to true when a method correctly executes, and false if it does not. When this property changes, for a few seconds I would like to display "Passed" or "Failed" on the status bar of my WPF application and then have it fade away.

So I have read StackOverflow, and Googled intensely, to no avail. I think I have misunderstood how I need to structure the Storyboard.

In my StatusBar I have added a storyboard, which I am trying to trigger in `<UserControl.Resources>` at the beginning of my XAML file. Is this correct ? At the moment I am using dummy values of 0/1, I assume the correct practice would be to use a BooleanToString converter I could make, or perhaps there is a better way?

So my status bar contains :

```
<StatusBar >
  <StatusBar.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="StatusBar" >
      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="statusBarItem">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="0"/>
      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
  </StatusBar.Resources>
</StatusBar>
```

and I am trying to register for this to be called in my UserControl.Resources :

<UserControl.Resources>

<DataTemplate.Triggers>



</DataTemplate.Triggers>

</UserControl.Resources>

Do I have my structure completely backwards ? It will not compile and I get the error :

```
A value of type 'BeginStoryboard' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'SetterBaseCollection'.
```

Any help, resources or information would be very much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example.  You need to use a trigger to start the storyboard.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <WpfApplication1:MainViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="statusStyle" TargetType="StatusBar">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Pulse}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                    AutoReverse="True" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" >
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="1"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StatusBar Style="{StaticResource statusStyle}" 
                       Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
    <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="16" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,30,0,0" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding Pulse}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

View model

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _pulse;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new[] {"Passed"};
    }

    public IList<string> Items { get; private set; }

    public bool Pulse
    {
        get { return _pulse; }
        set { Set(()=>Pulse, ref _pulse, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where can I find the implementation for the ViewModelBase?

Comment: @Guge If I remember that was from MVVM light.  All it's doing in this case is an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.